# How to temporarily re-name a file or Create a re-named temp-file in Python before zipping it

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, python-zipfile

In the below code I am trying to zip a list list of files, I am trying to rename the files before zipping it. So the file name will be in a more readable format for the user.

It works for the first time, but when I do it again It fails with the error the file name already exists

Returning the response via Django Rest Framework via FileResponse.
Is there any more simplistic way to achieve this?

```
filenames_list=['10_TEST_Comments_12/03/2021','10_TEST_Posts_04/10/2020','10_TEST_Likes_04/09/2020']
with zipfile.ZipFile(fr"reports/downloads/reports.zip", 'w') as zipF:
     for file in filenames_list:
            friendly_name = get_friendly_name(file)
            if friendly_name is not None:
               os.rename(file,fr"/reports/downloads/{friendly_name}")
               file = friendly_name
    
            zipF.write(fr"reports/downloads/{file}", file, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
zip_file = open(fr"reports/downloads/reports.zip", 'rb')
response = FileResponse(zip_file)
return response
```

Comment: You might want to look at library [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html)

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Right now you have a bunch of errors

Comment: @Mad Physicist
 corrected the indentations

Comment: @RossRogers. That does not apply here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ZipFile.write`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write) has a second parameter, `arcname`, which allows you to rename files without any copying. You don't need to move `file` to a separate folder, or actually rename it.

```
from os.path import basename

for file in filenames_list:
    if (name := get_friendly_name(file)) is None:
        name = basename(file)
zipF.write(file, name, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

By stripping off the [`basename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename), you avoid the need to move to a common folder at all.